# Is Qt 4.6 compiled with Cocoa by default on Snow Leopard?

Tags: c++, cocoa, qt, qt4, osx-snow-leopard

At work, I was told to configure and build Qt 4.6 with the cocoa flag

```
./configure -cocoa
```

Instead I just ran configure without any flags on my Mac OS X 10.6 machine.

Does that mean I have to reconfigure or is cocoa linked by default in Snow Leopard?

Alternatively, how can I check if my Qt build is linked against cocoa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this post](http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2009/08/31/qt-46-on-mac-os-106/) `-cocoa` is only default for 64 bit builds in 4.6 - you have to either supply the `-cocoa` or `-arch x86_64`.
If you want to make sure ask `configure` for its options and look for the defaults.

Answer (score 1):

Set your qt using project to build for 64bit or 32/64 hybrid. If it builds and links, it cocoa!

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be quickest just to run `configure` again?